# How to pick names with spaces and ` ' ` in cbind in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to pick column names that would allow spaces and special characters `'` in them. Specifically, I want to use `Cohen's d` as the column name for in `cbind()` below. But right now, I have to `Cohensd` otherwise I get an error.

How can I use `Cohen's d` in `cbind()` below?

```
cbind(Cohensd = c(1, 2), Mean.diff = c(3, 4) )
```

Comment: Unless this is for presentation purposes, it's a better idea to just use syntactic names.

Answer (score 2):

We can use backquotes

```
cbind(`Cohen's d` = c(1, 2), Mean.diff = c(3, 4) )
#     Cohen's d Mean.diff
#[1,]         1         3
#[2,]         2         4
```